# joystick for user control in iOS8 scenekit

Tags: iphone, uikit, game-engine, scenekit, uikit-dynamics

I am developing one game similar to bubble island(https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/bubble-island/id531354582?mt=8). 
In this I want to create control like when user click on any part of view, game displays the series of bubbles in the touch direction. If bubbles cross the screen boundary then it turns to the other direction. When user remove the touch then game fires the ball.
My question is how to develop this type of control in iOS. Do I need to use UIKIT, SpritKit or SceneKit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an overlay containing your joystick.
I use SceneKit in my application to generate my scene and I use SpriteKit for the overlay. I found this Joystick for my usecase: [SpriteKit-Joystick](https://github.com/TheSneakyNarwhal/SpriteKit-Joystick)